# Cannot launch upsource from docker image

Tags: upsource

Trying to launch upsource on docker container via instructions on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/docker-installation.html

`docker run -it --name upsource -v /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/data/:/opt/upsource/data -v /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/config/:/opt/upsource/conf -v /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/logs/:/opt/upsource/logs  -v /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/backups/:/opt/upsource/backups -p 8080:8080 jetbrains/upsource:2017.3.2888`

But my attempts are failed with: `Config directory is not writable: /opt/upsource/conf` error.

Ownership in `upsource/` direcotry:

`drwxr-x---   2 13001      13001              68  4 march 14:30 backups
drwxr-x---   2 13001      13001              68  4 march 14:30 config
drwxr-x---   2 13001      13001              68  4 march 14:30 data
drwxr-x---   2 13001      13001              68  4 march 14:30 logs`

ps: macOS (High Sierra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the service is not open to the web but you are using it locally you can set 777 privileges on those directories. That solved the problem in my case.

`(sudo) chmod -R 777 /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/[data|conf|logs|backups]`

I have macOS High Sierra as well. It looks like if the user and the group the container uses is not 13001:13001 but something else. Maybe the docker's user... That one I've not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Probably worth checking whether permissions for `upsource/` directory are set recursively.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:
docker run -it --privileged=true --name upsource -v /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/data/:/opt/upsource/data -v /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/config/:/opt/upsource/conf -v /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/logs/:/opt/upsource/logs  -v /Users/rudskoy/desktop/upsource/backups/:/opt/upsource/backups -p 8080:8080 jetbrains/upsource:2017.3.2888

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).